# PHP/MySQL won't update decimal field

Tags: php, mysql, double, decimal

I have this query:

```
UPDATE table_name 
  SET field_1 = field_1 +100,
      field_2 = field_2 +100,
      field_3 = field_3 +100
WHERE id = 1 
LIMIT 1;
```

Where Field_1 is regular integer, Field_2 is decimal(15,6) and  Field_3 is double(15,6).
When I run this query from php script they update just field_1 and nothing happen with field_2 and field_3 they just stay as before. But when I run in phpMyAdmin it's work without any problems.

I'm tried to lock tables, make round() before run update, nothing help.

Please help... why I can't update decimal and float fields from php?

PHP version: 5.2
Mysql version 5

---

Nothing help. But I found one small solution (I want to go away from it). When I run next query like

`INSERT INTO error SET error_type = ' ;`

Of course this is return error but previous query with update update all fields.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does an UPDATE without using the field work? eg field_3 = 100 instead of field_3 = field_3 + 100 ?

Comment: Try dropping the final LIMIT 1

Comment: Do you have more than one record where the id value is 1?  If the answer is "no", then the LIMIT is redundant.

Comment: No, UPDATE field_3 = 100 doesn't work.
Yes in table more then one field. And I'm already tried drop LIMIT without any luck

Comment: Does it have a default value ?? if field_2 == NULL then the query won't update that field

Comment: field_2 Not NULL Default 0.00000000

Comment: Yes I can post php cod but there around 500 lines in that page + other classes in other files. If you can tell me how can I post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible problems:

Locale. If You use non English - American locale, there is a chance, that Your numbers are interpreted incorrectly - decimal separator is not ".", but ",", just try insert "," instead of "." in Your float numbers and look what happens. If thats the case, You'll have to either write a converting function in PHP (which PHPAdmin has, thats why You don't face the problem there), or change the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to  require to convert the integral value 100 into decimal and double type values like this in your php script..
 $num=number_format (100, 6 ,'.',  '');
 After doing this..perfom the update operation by adding $num to the decimal and double type field values...